# is it able to access the file from main app in it's extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

In my main app I downloaded a file and saved it in this path

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDD34D1D-8A61-4195-B4BF-AA63BF5C9983/Library/Caches/downloads/YTQjmrJpEeSkyQIKTN1OKQ.jpg
```

and in the main app, I check the file existence with this codes:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];


        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:avatarPhysicalPath]){
            [self.lbName setText:@"fileExist!"];
        }
        else{
            [self.lbName setText:@"not..fileExist!"];
        }
```

it returns fileExist!.

however, I do the same in the watchkit app of this application, it return file not exist.
am I able to do so? and how?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access files from your extension as easily as that (but I'm not sur). But keep in mind that with WatchOS 2, the whole application will be on your watch ! So it wont be able to access your file on the phone for sure. Maybe the best way to access your file from your WatchKit extension is by using the openParentApplication method :)

Comment: thanks, but I am not developing for a WatchOS 2 app. just the old one.
What I am doing right now is to return NSData in the response of openParentApplication. Any better idea :)?

Comment: oh sory ^^ Well, that's the way I would have done that, but I also think you can do it with appGroups it's used to share data between apps as far as i know :)